# Wie sagt man »6 pack abs«?

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

> Ich trainiere jeden Tag, um eine 6 pack abs zu bekommen

Es gibt eine Übersetzung dafür im Internetwörterbuch Dict.cc, aber ich bin mir unsicher, ob sie zu meinem Satz passt:

> Ich treibe jeden Tag Sport, um eine Bauchmuskulatur zu bekommen.

Comment: Eine Bauchmuskulatur hast du sowieso, auch wenn du deinen Bauch nicht trainierst. Du kannst durchaus [Sixpack](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sixpack) sagen.

Comment: Unter jungen Leuten und in der BB Szene kann man die englischen Begriffe verwenden. Und wenn dein Bodyfat low genug ist, bekommst du ein Eightpack ;-)

Comment: Viele Menschen können gar kein Sixpack bekommen, selbst wenn sie bis zum Umfallen trainieren. Wieviele Querstränge nach langem Training sichtbar werden, ist genetisch bedingt, weil Bindegewebsstränge für die sichtbare Unterteilung verantwortlich sind, und diese Stränge sind nicht bei allem Menschen gleich angeordnet. Man kann sich durch Training keine zusätzlichen Bindegewebsstränge in der Bauchmuskulatur wachsen lassen.

Comment: Was soll denn '6 pack abs' sein? Englisch? Vielleicht kann jmd. die Frage korrigieren, der sie versteht. Einen Sechserpack-Abs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Du kannst beruhigt Sixpack sagen. Das Wort hat sich dafür durchgesetzt.

> Ich trainiere jeden Tag, um einen Sixpack zu bekommen.

Jeder Deutsche wird das als korrektes Deutsch verstehen.

Comment: Zum letzen Satz: Da bin ich mir nicht sicher. Es gibt tausende Deutsche die nicht deutsch sprechen. Andererseits gibt es rund 15 Millionen Menschen, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist, die aber nicht in Deutschland leben.

Comment: Ja, das ist leider auch wieder war. Es gibt leider viel zu Viele Deutsche die sich nicht in korrektem Deutsch ausdrücken können... :(

Comment: Es mag schon sein, dass viele Deutsch schlecht Deutsch sprechen, aber das meinte ich nicht. Ich meinte, dass es tausende in Deutschland lebende deutsche Staatsbürger gibt, die überhaupt nicht Deutsch sprechen (sondern Dänisch, Romani, Serbisch, Türkisch usw.), während es Millionen nichtdeutsche Deutsch-Muttersprachler gibt. Zur zweiten Gruppe gehören fast alle Österreicher, darunter ich. Was ich eigentlich sagen wollte: »Deutscher« und »Deutsch sprechender« sind zwei unterschiedliche Begriffe, die zwei unterschiedliche Teile der Menschheit bezeichnen.

Comment: (Fortsetzung): Wenn man sich auf Sprachen bezieht, sollte man jenen Begriff verwenden, der auch tatsächlich mit der Sprache verknüpft ist, und nicht den, der mit dem Wohnort bzw. der Staatsbürgerschaft verbunden ist. Man bezeichnet Menschen, deren Muttersprache Englisch ist, ja auch nicht als Engländer, sondern als Englischsprachige.

Answer (score 11):

I believe you can use the English term, but still the word used in solid German is ***Waschbrettbauch*** (m).

Answer (score 11):

*Sixpack* ist ein gebräuchlicher Anglizismus im Deutschen, der sowohl für trainierte und dadurch sichtbare Bauchmuskulatur (vor allem bei Männern) verwendet wird als auch für sechs Getränkegebinde in einem Paket oder Träger (meist Bierflaschen oder -dosen). *Abs* wird hingegen nicht verwendet und eher selten verstanden.

Die traditionelle deutsche Metapher für die Muskelstruktur ist hingegen das geriffelte Waschbrett (washboard), also *Waschbrettbauch*. Ein Antonym für den »dad bod«, das eher scherzhaft verwendet wird, wäre *Wasch**bär**bauch* (racoon belly). Auch dem Sixpack wird ggf. ein *Fässchen* (little keg) gegenübergestellt.